# How to set up do-while loop condition C++?

Tags: do-while

I need to make a menu where the user selects an option to input, but the menu options are selected with letters or numbers.

The menu will have options: s,d,1,2,3,4,r and q(to quit the program).

The user will input and then there will be if else statements to further guide compiler to what code needs to be ran and then it needs to return to the menu after all steps are completed.

However, I need the program to end not only when the user enters q, but when they input any response that is not on the menu. But I also need it to cout a statement before ending.

Do i define this parameter in the while condition and if so how do I got about it? And how do I make sure the statement is printed before the program ends.

Sorry, I am new to coding, and this is probably a stupid question and probably not asked accurately. But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can put a `switch` statement having those menu items as corresponding `case`s and bail out in `default` statement. But you better start coding and ask when it's not working.

Comment: You should code it by yourself and ask if you will have some specific problem with your code.

Comment: Sorry, I've coded it 4 different times different ways and was never getting the right result.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a basic example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   // Local variable declaration:
   int a = 10;

   // do loop execution
   do
   {
       cout << "value of a: " << a << endl;
       a = a + 1;
   }while( a < 20 );

   return 0;
}
```

When the above code is compiled and executed, it produces the following result:

```
value of a: 10
value of a: 11
value of a: 12
value of a: 13
value of a: 14
value of a: 15
value of a: 16
value of a: 17
value of a: 18
value of a: 19
```

You can find a lot of example and tutorial on google

Answer (score 0):

One of the simpler ways to do it would be to create a large while loop within which choices are made.  Within the loop you should request a value from the user, then go through a series of if/else statements on that value.  (case works too, but if/else is easier to understand at the beginning).

I've basically outlined the code below.  Sorry for any syntax errors, I've been looking at too much python lately.

```
keeplooping=True;
char choice;
while(keeplooping) {
    cout << "Make a choice";  //add user choices so they can see?

    cin >> choice;
    if(choice=='1') {
        //do something
    }
    else if(choice=='2') {
        //do something
    }
    //keep going....
    else if(choice=='q') {
        keeplooping=False
    }
    else  {
        keeplooping=False;
        cout << "Invalid choice";
    }
}
```